# x86 FASM assembly Reverse FizzBuzz

Tags: assembly, fizzbuzz

This program counts down from 100 to 1 and:

- If the current number is a multiple of 3 it prints "Fizz" instead of the number
- If it is a multiple of 5 it prints "Buzz" instead of the number
- If it is a multiple of 3 and 5 it prints "FizzBuzz" instead of the number

```
format PE console
entry main

include 'macro/import32.inc'

section '.rdata' data readable
msg db '%d',13,10, 0
fizz db 'Fizz', 13, 10, 0
buzz db 'Buzz', 13, 10, 0
p db 'pause>nul', 0
fizzbuzz db 'FizzBuzz', 13, 10, 0
section '.data' data readable writeable
vdiv_by_3 dd 0
vdiv_by_5 dd 0

main:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

mov ecx, 100

load_3:
mov eax, ecx
mov ebx, 3
xor edx, edx
div ebx
mov ebx, edx 
mov [vdiv_by_3], ebx ; Store the remainder in div_by_3

load_5: ; Now check if its divisible by 5
mov eax, ecx
mov ebx, 5
xor edx, edx
div ebx
mov [vdiv_by_5], edx ; Remainder in div_by_5

cmp edx, 0 ; Checking 5
jne check_3_not_5

check_3:
mov eax, [vdiv_by_3]
cmp eax, 0
je print_fizzbuzz

check_3_not_5:
mov eax, [vdiv_by_3]
cmp eax, 0
je print_fizz

check_5_not_3:
mov eax, [vdiv_by_5]
cmp eax, 0
je print_buzz

print_num: ; Problem: This is printing 101 first, we need to start at 1
push ecx
push msg
call [printf] ; This call will mess with ecx so we have to store it
add esp, 4
pop ecx ; Get the counter back into ecx
jmp endme

print_fizz:
push ecx
push fizz
call [printf]
add esp, 4
pop ecx
jmp endme

print_buzz:
push ecx
push buzz
call [printf]
add esp, 4
pop ecx
jmp endme

print_fizzbuzz:
push ecx
push fizzbuzz
call [printf]
add esp, 4
pop ecx
jmp endme

print_number:
push ecx
push msg
call [printf]
add esp, 4
pop ecx

endme:
dec ecx
cmp ecx, 0
jne load_3
push p
call [system]
add esp, 4
push 0
call [exit]


section '.idata' import data readable
library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'
import msvcrt, \
printf, 'printf', \
system, 'system', \
exit, 'exit'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are writing FizzBuzz in assembler, you are obviously concerned about performance and code size.

For performance, `div` is one of the worst instructions. Since the divisibility repeats modulo 15, you could define some constants:

```
const divisible_by_3 = 0b1001001001001001
const divisible_by_5 = 0b1000010000100001
```

To test the divisibility, have an extra register that is initialized with `i mod 15` and adjusted whenever `i` changes. The basic idea is:

```
dec i
dec i_mod_15
cmovs i_mod_15, 14   ; the maximum value mod 15
```

You can also combine `divisible_by_3` and `divisible_by_5` into a bit vector of two-bit entries (`divisible`) and define a jump table based on that. To do the actual testing, use bit-shifting.

```
const divisible_by_3 = 0b_1_0_0_1_0_0_1_0_0_1_0_0_1_0_0_1
const divisible_by_5 = 0b1_0_0_0_0_1_0_0_0_0_1_0_0_0_0_1_
const divisible      = 0b11000001001001000001100001000011
```

Another idea is to use unroll the loop by using Duff's Device.

Right now, your code is a really boring, straight-forward translation of some higher-level language, probably C. In assembler, you have much more potential to compress the code (DRY principle). For example, you can `jmp do_printf` instead of writing `push ecx; call printf; pop ecx` several times.

---

… 90 minutes later …

---

Based on the above ideas, the code might look like this, tested and works.

```
format PE console
entry main

include 'macro/import32.inc'

section '.rdata' data readable

; Each of these messages takes exactly 8 bytes,
; except for the last one.
; This is important for addressing them efficiently.
messages db '%d', 13, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0
         db 'Fizz', 13, 10, 0, 0
         db 'Buzz', 13, 10, 0, 0
         db 'FizzBuzz', 13, 10, 0

; This bit mask selects one of the above messages
; to be printed. The counter is always passed to
; printf, and in 8/15 cases it is ignored.
; The uu entry at the end is unused.
;
;                0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
; div3 mask =    1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  u
; div5 mask =   1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  u
div_mask =      11_00_00_01_00_10_01_00_00_01_10_00_01_00_00_00b

section '.text' code readable

main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        mov ecx, 100            ; ecx = the counter
        mov eax, ecx
        xor edx, edx
        mov ebx, 15
        div ebx                 ; edx = counter mod 15

        mov ebx, div_mask       ; ebx = bit mask for selecting the message
        rol ebx, 2
        xchg edx, ecx           ; Variable-width rotation is only possible
        rol ebx, cl             ; with cl, therefore the temporary swap
        rol ebx, cl             ; of edx and ecx.
        xchg edx, ecx           ;

.again:
        mov eax, ebx            ; Select the message format for printf.
        and eax, 11b
        shl eax, 3
        add eax, messages

        push ebx                ; save registers before printf
        push ecx
        push edx

        push ecx                ; actually call printf
        push eax
        call [printf]
        add esp, 8

        pop edx                 ; restore registers after printf
        pop ecx
        pop ebx

        dec edx                 ; Adjust counter, counter mod 15
        jns .normal             ; and bit mask.
        add edx, 15
        ror ebx, 2              ; Rotate one extra time since
.normal:                        ; the bit mask has 16 entries.
        ror ebx, 2

        dec ecx
        jnz .again

        xor eax, eax
        pop ebp
        ret

section '.idata' import data readable

library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

import msvcrt, printf, 'printf', system, 'system'
```

Some more things I took care of:

- The code must not be in a writeable section.
- Since the program can return from `main`, it should do so. To make that work, I had to add the `pop ebp` that corresponds to the `push ebp` at the very top; in your code that was missing.
- I carefully avoided many branching statements, since they are poisonous to performance. See [Why is it faster to process a sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809).
- The one remaining conditional behaves well in that it follows the jump in 14/15 cases, which is easily predictable.
- Of course, using `printf` and the C stdio for output ruins all performance effects. But that's outside the scope for this little fun experiment.
- All arguments to `printf` may be modified by `printf`. There's no guarantee that you get your `ecx` back at the point where you commented `; Get the counter back into ecx`. To hide the counter from `printf`, you must push it once more to the stack. That's why I explicitly commented on this saving/calling/restoring in my code.

A nice thing is that you can play with the bit mask, which feels just like an ordinary configuration file.

Comment: Roland thanks for this very high quality answer. It is exactly what I am looking for - how a true “assembly programmer” can approach a problem. Can you provide a link about how I could do this without the c library which you says negates performance?? And any other resource you recommend for “thinking like an assembly programmer?” Thanks again.

Comment: Replacing `printf` with something more efficient is not trivial. The main takeaway here is that in I/O-bound code, there's no point in optimizing the remaining code. For further reading and thinking I suggest the book "Hacker's Delight", an essential piece of artwork that every assembler programmer should know. — By the way, thanks for writing your code so well and simple, it was a great foundation for putting my experiment on top of. I fear that my code is not as easy to modify or adapt.

Comment: The point is: if you replace printf, you have to call two different functions for the "number" and the "word" case, plus you have to do the I/O buffering yourself since system calls are slow. You could certainly call `WriteFile` instead of printf, but then you also have to implement the number formatting yourself.

Comment: @RolandIllig valuable answer :)